# Getting the index of a value having multiple positions in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

Good Day, I am currently looking for a way to find all index of a value in any array. This value may appear more than once in that array. I could use the `.includes` and `.indexOf` to find the first position only, something like

```
function indexOfValue(needle, hayStack) {
    if(hayStack.includes(needle)) {
        return hayStack.indexOf(needle);
    }
}
console.log(indexOfValue(12, [12, 1, 3, 3, 6, 12]));
```

But this `log` the `value` of only the first position of the needle.

This is what i have tried to get all `index`

```
function indexOfValue(needle, hayStack) {
    let result = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < hayStack.length; i++) {
        if (hayStack.includes(needle)) {
            return result.push(hayStack[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
console.log(indexOfValue(12, [12, 1, 3, 3, 6, 12]));
```

But the above code for some reason returns `1` instead of `[0,5]`. Pleas what is the issue with this particular code and how do i go about fixing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning `result.push` cuts your iteration short, and doesn't even include the index. Instead check if each element is equal to the needle, and then push the index if it's equal.

```js
function indexOfValue(needle, hayStack) {
    let result = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < hayStack.length; i++) {
        if (hayStack[i] === needle) { // check if matching
            result.push(i); //push the index
        }
    } return result; //return result at end
}
console.log(indexOfValue(12, [12, 1, 3, 3, 6, 12]))
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is that your are returning too early.

Every time you `return` from a function, you exit the function, stopping the rest of the code from executing/running within it.

So, as you are `return`ing in your for loop, you are stopping your loop from doing any other checks. This means you should return after your loop is completely done.

Moreover, you also need to fix your `if` statement in your for loop. At the moment you are checking if the array you pass in (`hayStack`) has the item (`needle`) you are looking for. Instead, you need to check if the current item (using `haystack[i]`) is the `needle`, then if it is you need to push `i` (which is the current index) into your `result` array.

See working example below:

```js
function indexOfValue(needle, hayStack) {
    let result = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < hayStack.length; i++) { // loop through the array, where `i` is the current index in the array
        if (hayStack[i] === needle) { // check if a given number inthe array is the `needle`, if it is:
            result.push(i); // add the index of the item to the result array
        }
    }
    return result; // only once the loop is complete return the array
}
console.log(indexOfValue(12, [12, 1, 3, 3, 6, 12]));
```

If you wish, you can also achieve the same task using high-order functions such as `reduce`:

```js
const indexOfValue = (n, arr, i) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, num, i) => num === n ? [...acc, i] : acc, [])

console.log(indexOfValue(12, [12, 1, 3, 3, 6, 12]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Both code examples at the question `return`s within the `for` loop. The second example `.push()`s the element to the `result` array, not the `index`.

You can use the second parameter of `.indexOf()` to set the index to start the search from, check if result of `.indexOf()` is greater than `-1` and the index is not in `result` array, `return` `result` array after `for` loop

```js
function indexOfValue(needle, hayStack) {
    let result = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < hayStack.length; i++) {
        let index = hayStack.indexOf(needle, i);
        if (index > -1 && result.indexOf(index) === -1) {
           result.push(index);
        }       
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(indexOfValue(12, [12, 1, 3, 3, 6, 12]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const numbers = [11, 3, 6, 8, 11];

const indexOfValue = (val,numbers) =>{
  let filtered =[];
  numbers.filter((number,index) => {   
    if(val === number)
       filtered = [...filtered,index];
  })
  return filtered;
}
console.log(indexOfValue(11,numbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop though whole array and create an array for indexes of the number. Like below

```js
function indexOfValue(num,arr){
  let indexes = [];
  for(let i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
    //checks if the element at index 'i' is "num" then push index 'i' into indexes array
    if(arr[i] === num) indexes.push(i);
  }
  return indexes;
}

console.log(indexOfValue(12, [12, 1, 3, 3, 6, 12]))
```